# Implement Editable Order of Items in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, reactjs, express

I would like to show a table of items, where user can add, delete and reorder the items. The first way I thought to store these items in MySQL DB was to have an order column in the table, but it seems pretty inefficient because when user deletes an item, I need to update the order of all the following items. And if I just use ORDER BY with id or something, I don't know how to let user reorder the items as they want. What do you think is the best way to handle this?

The stack I use: React JS -> Node JS / Express -> MySQL

Comment: If you're thinking that the `order` column you're proposing a) has to be an integer and b) has to contain no gaps then you will have the problem you anticipate. But if you accept gaps, there's no need to update other items on delete. and if you use floats or equivalent then inserting an item between two other items just needs you to find the average of their current order values (Occasionally, this will break down if there's lots of activity, but you can have a "one-off" re-sorting of the whole table when this happens, still leaving the average cost low)

Comment: E.g., if my insert comment isn't obvious. If you want to insert a new item between the items currently assigned orders 4 and 5, you assign it the order value ((4+5)/2) = 4.5

Comment: Inserting in between is not a concern, the addition will always be to the tail. However, If I accept gaps, it feels like the order might get out of control, since there will be a lot of deletions and with gaps there will be a lot of unused numbers

Comment: When you're using floats or decimals, most numbers are unused. Choose any two numbers, and there are more numbers between them. Even if you used integers and had unused numbers, why on earth would that be a problem anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You'll definitely need a new column to do this ordering. It requires the storage of more information than you can represent with just the item ID, name, and all that.

I have done this successfully with the kind of `order` column you mention.  Here are some tricks I used.

- Don't worry about what happens when you delete a row. Things work just fine if you have gaps in the values of your `order` column.
- Use the same data type for your `order` column as your autoincrementing `id` column (`BIGINT UNSIGNED` probably) but allow NULL values.
- Use `ORDER BY COALESCE(order, id * 1000), id` so you'll use the `id` value for ordering newly inserted rows that have never had their order set. New rows come at the end. Intutitive enough default behavior.
- To put item with id `a` right after the item with id `b`, update the `order` value in row `a` to `COALESCE(b.order, id * 1000) + 1`.

Like this

```
id    name    order   COALESCE(order, id*1000)
1     orange  NULL    1000
2     banana  NULL    2000
3     apple   NULL    3000
4     fig     NULL    4000
```

This makes your order values be 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000 and so forth. To order the fourth item right after the second item you'll set its `order` to 2001. Like this

```
id    name    order   COALESCE(order, id*1000)
1     orange  NULL    1000
2     banana  NULL    2000
4     fig     2001    2001
3     apple   NULL    3000
```

If you do enough reordering that you insert more than 1000 items after any given item, you'll have to clean up your `order` column by rewriting it for the whole table.  It's OK if you have some identical `order` values. The `ORDER BY` clause I suggested will keep them in their original ID order.

Answer (score 0):

A way I have seen is to have a sperate column which states the ID of the item it is behind. Then in your Query you can order from that column when selecting to make it display in that order.

This means that if you delete a field, you only have to update the one behind it to then state its behind the one ahead of what you just deleted (That was a jumple of words...)

Does this help?

Comment: Part of me feels like I completely missed the point of your question!